# How Do I Get Rid Of Moles

Tags: pests

How can I prevent, get rid of moles in my yard?  I have tried traps and the glandular poison.
Moles come back every spring.

Comment: And do you mean 'granular', not 'glandular'?

Comment: Hi Eric and welcome to the site. As you can see, there's already a question that's similar to yours. Hopefully there's an answer there that will help you. If not, feel free to ask for clarification over on that question or ask a new question. We're glad you're here and hope you stick around.

Comment: Please stop your war with these little guys.  Think of them as cheap labor!  Although you may have dozens of soil hills, there are probably just a couple of moles/voles/ground squirrels burrowing through your soil eating mostly grubs, larvae that ARE potentially damaging to your grass. These little guys AERATE your lawn's compacted soil.  For free.  I charged big bucks to have my crews dump new soil and/or mulch in piles all over gorgeous lawns.  Using a blower and/or rakes, these piles are knocked down and spread thinly...enhancing your lawn's soil and environment. For Free...good guys!